# MySQL reverse string by pair of two

Tags: mysql

In a MySQL database, I have a table that contains a colour in `TColor` (Delphi) format. I would like to convert it to `hex`.

```
|----|-----------|---------------------------|----------|
| id |   TColor  | LPAD(HEX(TColor), 6, '0') |  ??????  |
|----|-----------|---------------------------|----------|
|  1 |      255  |                    0000FF |  FF0000  |
|----|-----------|---------------------------|----------|
|  2 |    39423  |                    008080 |  808000  |
|----|-----------|---------------------------|----------|
|  3 |  8421504  |                    808080 |  808080  |
|----|-----------|---------------------------|----------|
```

Normal `REVERSE()` won't cut it, as the output is `BBGGRR` where only the colour order is in reverse, not the whole string.

In JS I solved it by splitting it by pairs of 2, reversing the array, and joining it back...

But how to solve this in MySQL?

Comment: with [string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) in a very similary way to JS.

Comment: which data type is the column  Tcolor ???

Comment: @scaisEdge number actually

Comment: @danblack There is a lot of them, I am not sure what would fit best... The only thing I can think of would be the use of 3 `SUBSTRING(LPAD(HEX()))` and `CONCAT`

Comment: Number .. which type?? ..  hex ???  check the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this isn't a string function, its a mathematical rotation of bits.

Looking at [this](http://www.acasystems.com/en/color-picker/faq-delphi-tcolor.htm) there is no alpha. And the Delphi Tcolor form is 00BBGGRR.

To transform to RRGGBB

```
  ((TColor & 0xff) << 16 )      /* The RR shifted left by 2 bytes */
  | ((TColor & 0xff0000) >> 16) /* The BB shifted right by 2 bytes */
  | (TColor & 0x00FF00 )      /* The GG kept as it is */
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=05440c2cc7187c660818230675ea797e)

Note: other Tcolor forms exist and require a different transformation.

Comment: It is adding 2 more numbers/characters to the end, is it ok?

Comment: you'll need to be more specific in the mapping. AABBCCDD -> ?. 2 more hex digits means it becomes 32 bits.

Comment: The result consists of 4 pairs, I suppose it is `RRGGBBAA`, if the `AA` is alpha, it is key and I can strip it, but I am not sure it is alpha.

Comment: Sorry did not saw, you actually edited the answer and fixed it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Once TColor is cast as   a string you coul try

```
select  HEX(concat(substr(Tcolor, 4,2),substr(Tcolor, 0,4)))
```

eg using  UNHEX()

```
select  HEX(concat(substr(unhex(Tcolor), 4,2),substr(unhex(Tcolor), 0,4)))
```

for integr you could try using CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), Tcolor)

Comment: Sorry, the number is INT(11)